# Magento 2 in how to add all products website id in main website?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, admin-panel, phtml, csv

i will try to database table values in website id in main website but not working.?

[image]

how to bulk change the all products website id change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto Admin panel select category menu in select all products,click the action in Update all attributes and click the checkbox and click the save button.

[image]

It's Working.!

Answer (score 0):

**Step - 1** :- Click - Catalog Menu on Left Side then Click Products Menu

**Step - 2** :- Click on 1st Check Box Drop Down Icon - Before ID Column - Click Select All

**Step - 3** :- Click on Actions - Update Attributes - Click on Websites on Left Side

**Step - 4** :- You can see the Add Product to Website - Click on Store Checkbox & Click on Save on Top Right

Once you saved. Try running the commands to see the changes

```
php bin/magento cron:run && php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Check the screenshots for more information**

[image]

[image]

[image]